# How to count the number of duplicates in a 2d array? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

What's up everyone,
I have to create an algorithm that creates a 5x5 array filled with random numbers from 0 to 9 and then it counts how many times each number appears in the array. My base code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i,j,a=0;
    int tab[5][5];
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            tab[i][j] = rand()%10;
            cout << tab[i][j] << "|";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now I don't know how to do the second part. I can just create 10 new integers and use brute force to do it, but I want the code to look cleaner and more efficient. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::map`?

Comment: One solution would be to create a seperate array enough for 10 integers, then increment the index each time you see that specific digit.

Comment: Show your brute force idea, then describe what the problem is. If there is no problem other than "not cool, not clean, not efficient", then consider asking for a review. But read their rules beforehand.

Comment: I'm fairly new to c++, so I don't know what std::map is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std::unordered_map is a good solution for your problem. The following function template will do your job. Note that the solution presented by @aaijmrt is not really hashing and will not be efficient when you are generating random numbers in a larger range (say from 0 to 10000000).

```
template<typename Key, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols>
std::unordered_map<Key, size_t> countFrequency(Key Arr[rows][cols], Key(&)[rows][cols]){

    std::unordered_map<Key,size_t> freq;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

            Key k = *((*Arr+i*cols)+j);

            if(freq.find(k)!=freq.end())
                freq[k] = freq[k]+1;
            else
                freq.insert({k,1});
        }
    }

    return freq;
}
```

Call the above function like this

```
auto freq = countFrequency(tab, tab);
for(const auto elem : freq) std::cout<<elem.first<<" "<<elem.second<<"\n";
```

The template machinery is just for convenience and you can get rid of it like this

```
std::unordered_map<int, size_t> countFrequency(size_t rows, size_t cols, int Arr[5][5]){
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Identity_hash_function). ith index of the vector contains the frequency of i.

Something like this.

```
vector<int> getFreq(size_t rows, size_t cols, int **a) {
    vector<int> ans(9);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            ans[a[i][j]]++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```